# How to select rows based on filter condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below

```
acct_nbr    counter_1   Counter_2   counter_3
1234           1           1           1
2345           0           2           1
5678           1           0           1
9876           0           0           1
4567           1           0           0
2804           0           1           1
4321           2           1           1
```

i need to generate output based on counters. If all three counters are 1 or one of the counters is 1 and others are not greater than 1 then i need those rows in the result set.
Expected output:

```
acct_nbr    counter_1   Counter_2   counter_3
1234           1           1           1
5678           1           0           1
9876           0           0           1
4567           1           0           0
2804           0           1           1
```

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE counter_1 = 1 OR Counter_2 = 1 OR counter_3 = 1
```

But this is returning all the rows. Can you help me fix my query to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Your description appears to be:

```
where greatest(counter_1, counter_2, counter_3) <= 1
```

Or:

```
WHERE counter_1 <= 1 AND Counter_2 <= 1 AND counter_3 <= 1
```

Or, based on your comment -- assuming that the values are all non-negative:

```
where greatest(counter_1, counter_2, counter_3) <= 1 and
      least(counter_1, counter_2, counter_3) > 0
```

Comment: thanks for your response. WHERE counter_1 <= 1 AND Counter_2 <= 1 AND counter_3 <= 1 sounds appropriate, but if i have all the three counters as 0 then also i don't want that row. But this condition will return such rows. How to filter those as well

Comment: WHERE  ( counter_1 = 1 OR counter_2 = 1 OR counter_3 = 1 )
AND    counter_1 <= 1
AND    counter_2 <= 1
AND    counter_3 <= 1 this has solved the problem. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ( counter_1 = 1 OR counter_2 = 1 OR counter_3 = 1 )
AND    counter_1 <= 1
AND    counter_2 <= 1
AND    counter_3 <= 1
```

or (although a simpler query, Oracle would not use an index on the columns and would require a function-based index):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  GREATEST( counter_1, counter_2, counter_3 ) = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( acct_nbr, counter_1, Counter_2, counter_3 ) AS
SELECT 1234, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2345, 0, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5678, 1, 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9876, 0, 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4567, 1, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2804, 0, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4321, 2, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7654, 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCT_NBR | COUNTER_1 | COUNTER_2 | COUNTER_3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | 5678 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
> | 9876 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
> | 4567 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
> | 2804 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=635f076a27be4d6c5a98ea5b82774478)*

---

> i need to filter our rows if all three counters are 0 as well.

Assuming this is asking to include rows when all 3 values are zero then you can use (assuming only non-negative integer values):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  counter_1 IN ( 0, 1 )
AND    counter_2 IN ( 0, 1 )
AND    counter_3 IN ( 0, 1 )
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  GREATEST( counter_1, counter_2, counter_3 ) <= 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4790c22288919ee364656de82b65e68b)*

Comment: This works.. i need to filter our rows if all three counters are 0 as well. So can i use <> 1 in all the three AND conditions?

Comment: @user15906795 Having `0`, `0`, `0` does not match with the requirements in the question.

Comment: even if i have 0,0,0 i guess it works. As all the three expressions in OR will become FALSE and the result with other AND conditions will also FALSE. Please correct if i interpreted it wrong

Comment: @user15906795 If you do not want `0`, `0`, `0` then the top two queries will give you that result. If you do want `0`, `0`, `0` then the bottom two queries will give that alternative result. It is unclear from your first comment which result you expect.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i should have included a row with all three counters as 0s in my input table. But the first set of queries will solve the problem. Once again thanks for the solution